# Find matching range & replace adjacent cell value -- Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, replace

I have two data sets that I need to compare--one that contains my master data set, and a second with corrected values for one variable in that data set.

For instance,

Data Set:

```
FirstName1 | LastName1 | UserID1 | etc1 | etc1  
FirstName2 | LastName2 | UserID2 | etc2 | etc2  
FirstName3 | LastName3 | UserID3 | etc3 | etc3
```

and so on.

However, the User ID column is incorrect and needs to be updated with values from a separate sheet:

```
FirstName1 | LastName1 | **Corrected**UserID1  
FirstName2 | LastName2 | **Corrected**UserID2  
FirstName3 | LastName3 | **Corrected**UserID3
```

and so on.

**My objective is to find a match using the first two cells as criteria, then if a match is found, replace the User ID in the first sheet accordingly.** Unfortunately, the original data set is much smaller (~3k rows) than the sheet where the corrections are coming from (~30k rows), so a simpler solution has not yet been identified.

My VBA skills are poor (typical, I know) and this is as far as I have come:

```
Sub FindReplace()
  Dim lr As Long, i As Long
  With Sheets("Data Set")
    lr = .Range("A:B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lr To 1
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(.Range("A1:B1").Value, Sheets("Values").Range("A1:B1").Value, 0)) Then 
          .Cells("C1").Value = Sheets("Values").Cells("C1")
        End If
    Next i
  End With
End Sub
```

However, this doesn't do anything and I'm a bit stumped (and over my head). Ideally, I would appreciate some additional explanation of why the above *doesn't* work so that I might learn from my mistakes, but any help at all is infinitely appreciated.

Many thanks for the assistance!

+ds

Comment: Have you tried using vlookup() function? http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Vlookup-Tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex stated, you don't need VBA, a VLookup will work just fine.  You can concatenate both criteria into a third column on both sheets, then vlookup against that value.

Just make sure your concatenated column is at the left of the ID that you would like to retrieve.

```
FirstName1LastName1 |FirstName1 | LastName1 | CorrectedUserID1
FirstName2LastName2 |FirstName2 | LastName2 | CorrectedUserID2
FirstName3LastName3 |FirstName3 | LastName3 | CorrectedUserID3
```

Once you get your IDs updated, hard-code the formulas with a copy/pastespecial:values, and delete the concatenated column.

Comment: Thank you for the tip RE: VLookup. I have avoided spending much time with that function as I didn't think it suited my purposes.  

My objective here is to require as little manipulation of the data as possible as this will likely be repeated with other data sets as the need arises, hence the desire for VBA instead of a conventional formula w/ concatenation, etc.

Comment: I have, in the past, used VBA to create concatenation/vlookup columns.  Excel is optimized for this and it is vastly more efficient than a loop.  Of course it's your prerogative, but there's no reason you couldn't use both.

Answer (score 2):

Without getting into building and testing this, I can see that you have a typo.

```
Sub FindReplace()
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
With Sheets("Data Set")
    lr = .Range("A:B").End(xlUp).Row
    **For i = lr To 1**
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(.Range("A1:B1").Value, Sheets("Values").Range("A1:B1").Value, 0)) Then .Cells("C1").Value = Sheets("Values").Cells("C1")
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Should be

```
    For i = 1 To lr
```

Comment: Thanks, PJ. I have corrected the typo (as well as one other), but that doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Comment: This line is also problematic:  _.Cells("C1").Value = Sheets("Values").Cells("C1")_  Regardless of the check criteria, you've got the same C1 updating from C1 on a different sheet over and over.  Maybe it should be _.Cells("C" & i).Value = Sheets("Values").Cells("C" & i)_?

Comment: If anything, Range("C1") is the correct format there.